# Vector normalization gives very imprecise results

Tags: java, mathematics, vector

When I normalize vectors I receive very strange results. The lengths of the normalized vectors range from 1.0 to almost 1.5. The functions are all written by me, but I just can't find a mistake in my algorithm. When I normalize I just divide all components of the vector by the vector's length.

```
public double length(){
    return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
}

public void normalize(){
    if(length() > 0){
        x /= length();
        y /= length();
    }
}
```

Is this supposed to happen? I mean I can see the length ranging from 0.9 to 1.1 at worst, but this is just overwhelming.

Cheers

Comment: For your vector **functions**, how are they any different from other math **functions**?  If it truly is a function, make it, like all the **functions** in the `Math` class, `static`.  Maybe you need to put this into `StaticVectorFunctions`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The third call to `length()` in your function uses the updated `x` value. You really don't want that.

Calculate the length once, then divide `x` and `y`.

```
double len = length();
if (len > 0) {
  x /= len;
  y /= len;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that almost immediately after posting. But still thanks for taking the time to answer. It might be helpful to others stuck in the same tricky problem.